# De onde vem a palavra "gringo"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro

O título já diz tudo: qual(is) é(são) a(s) origem(ns) da palavra "gringo", que no Brasil é usada como sinônimo de estrangeiro, alguém que não é brasileiro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Gringo* foi importado do espanhol, como se pode ver no [Aulete digital:](http://www.aulete.com.br/gringo)

> ***gringo*** sm.
> **1.** Bras. Pej. Pop. Pessoa estrangeira: *No carnaval, o Rio fica cheio de gringos.*
> **2.** Bras. N.E. Pop. Mercador ambulante estrangeiro. [Col. gringada, gringalhada.]
> [F.: Do espn. *gringo*.]

*Gringo* já aparece como brasileirismo com o significado de ‘estrangeiro’ no Dicionário de Cândido Figueiredo de 1913. Mas parece que inicialmente o termo se aplicava apenas aos argentinos, como sugere esta passagem de 1876 em [*A Baroneza de Amor*](http://www.brasiliana.usp.br/handle/1918/01064510#page/35/mode/1up) (1876) de Joaquim Manuel de Macedo, a mais antiga em português em que encontrei o termo (p. 25; grafia original, meu negrito):

> [O] capitão Avante tomou-se de ogerisa com os argentinos: escrevendo ao pai, dizia-lhe ás vezes em suas cartas: « os ***gringos*** são peiores do que os paraguaios.»
>
> Para o capitão Avante *o **gringo*** era o peior dos homens; mas preciso é dizel-o, nesse preconceito mesquinho elle tinha a desculpa da desforra.

Em espanhol, *gringo* é sobretudo adjetivo, ‘estrangeiro’, aplicando-se quer a pessoas quer a línguas. O [dicionário da  Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JY0Q3cz) diz que a etimologia é controversa. No entanto o dicionário Houaiss informa que segundo Joan Corominas *gringo* é uma deformação de *griego* ('grego'): *griego* > *grigo* > *gringo*; teria primeiro significado apenas língua ininteligível, passando depois a aplicar-se também às pessoas que as falavam.

Comment: Tenho a ideia de ver em filmes de *hollywood*, quando há envolvência com Mexicanos, de eles dizerem *gringo* em relação aos Americanos...

Comment: @JorgeB. Também era daí que eu conhecia *gringo* , com esse significado. Curiosamente o dicionário da Academia espanhola diz que *gringo* significa *americano (EUA)* numa porção de países latino-americanos, mas não inclui o México.

Comment: Jacinto isso é no mínimo curioso...

Comment: @JorgeB. Pode ser que no México *gringo* signifique estrangeiro em geral. Vê o dicionário, tenho o link na resposta.

Comment: Sim eu estive a ver o dicionário.

Comment: De fato, costumamos chamar estrangeiros (em geral) de *gringos*. Mas um fato curioso ocorre no sul do Brasil: lá também chama-se especificamente quem tem sotaque italiano de gringo. Um bom exemplo é o governador do estado do Rio Grande do Sul, que é muito chamado de gringo por sua descendência e forma de se expressar muito parecida com a dos italianos. Uma busca na web por "Sartori gringo" e poderão confirmar isso :-)

Comment: @eightShirt Isso pode ser influência argentina: na Argentina, no passado, *gringo* aplicava-se sobretudo a italianos.

Comment: Duvido muito que "gringo" venha de "griego", já que ninguém diz "cingo" em vez de "ciego"...

Comment: É "dizel-o" um lapso na publicação, ou é intencional?

Comment: @someonewithpc Intencional: era mesmo assim que se escrevia no séc. XIX. Se ainda não leste Eça de Quiroz, Júlio Dinis ou outro da época na grafia original, experimenta. É um fartote...

Comment: @Luís O que o Carominas diz é que *ie* > *i* (*griego* > *grigo*) é comum no castelhano; a adição do ***n*** (*grigo* > *gringo*) seria por imitação; talvez de um som comum na fala de estrangeiros (e.g. irlandeses em Madrid no séc. XVIII) ou alguma palavra castelhana como *ringo-ringo* ('coisa espalhafatosa'). Vê [esta resposta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/meaning-and-connotations-of-gringo/17890#17890) para mais pormenores. Nós temos o *franciú*, mas não *ingliú* ou *chiniú*.